# What does HFA stand for in Coverity Prevent?

Tags: abbreviation, coverity-prevent

[Coverity Prevent](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coverity#Products) has a checker 'HFA' which is used to identify unused included header files.

I understand what it's used for, but I don't understand the abbreviation. What does HFA stand for?

It doesn't appear to be mentioned in the documentation and a quick bit of googling hasn't turned anything up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm guessing at header file analyzer.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, Header File Analysis (HFA) is the name of the checker.  You may not wish to turn it on for every analysis run (particularly if you do it multiple times per day or even every day).  The process by which you fix your header files may be a separate, less frequent process than daily bug fixes and also removing it from your frequent runs may help improve performance a bit.  We've seen some folks just run HFA once a week/month or on demand.

Answer (score 1):

HFA stands for "header file analysis" (not header file analyzer). From the [Coverity Prevent 4.5 Checker Reference](http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache%3ak-ERdkr5gAkJ%3ascan2.coverity.com:7479/doc/checker_ref.html+site%3acoverity.com+header+file+analyzer+hfa+Prevent&cd=2&hl=en&ct=clnk) (apparently only available in the Google cache):

> The HFA (header file analysis) checker finds many instances of unnecessary header file includes.